# Button Zoom on a table layout

Tags: android, android-xml, tablelayout, pinchzoom

I have a dynamic generated tablerows of a table layout inside a parent scrollview and a horizontal scrollview.

I want to implement button or pinch zoom on this table layout. How to do it? Any one of the two which is easier to implement will do.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView android:layout_below="@+id/tableHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollZoomView">

            <TableLayout android:stretchColumns="0,1" android:id="@+id/main_table"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Edited to add Java code:

```
    zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            zoom(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    });

    zoomOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            zoom(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    });

public void zoom(float scalex, float scaley, float pivotx, float pivoty){
    sv.setScaleX(scalex);
    sv.setScaleY(scaley);
    sv.setPivotX(pivotx);
    sv.setPivotY(pivoty);
    sv.requestLayout();
}
```

Problem i am getting is that the scroll width and height are not updating itself to fit the enlarged data. For example there are 100 rows in table. Now after i zoom in, i am able to scroll till 80th row with enlarged text. When i zoom out, BAM! i see the 100th row in normal size.

I have added the

```
 sv.requestLayout();
```

also tried

```
 invalidate();
```

nothing worked.

What is the problem here ? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried altering the values of [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)?

```
TableLayout mainTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

zoomView(view, 1.5); // Zoom in to 150%
zoomView(view, 0.5); // Zoom out to 50%


function zoomView(View view, int zoomX){
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    viewParams.width *= zoomX;
    viewParams.height *= zoomX;
    view.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
}
```

Note: This would just scale your `TableLayout` but you will have to make the child `View`s fluid so that they adjust according to the parent layout.

Comment: this does not seem to work. please check updated question for java code. what i tired out.